# I'v installed php sockets module but cannot use

Tags: php, sockets

i install sockets module with source code.

```
/../php-5.6.24/ext/sockets/
/opt/php/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/php/bin/php-config --prefix=/opt/php --enable-sockets
make && make install
```

add to php.ini

```
extension="/opt/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/sockets.so"
```

than, the module has existed in :

```
/opt/php/bin/php -m
```

but it not found in phpinfo, and can not use function socket_create().

Comment: Double-check the php.ini path in phpinfo to see if you added it to the correct one. Usually, CLI uses a different one, so could report different modules being installed.

Answer (score 0):

i'v restart the linux server and httpd server ,but still fail.
finally,i reinstall php-5.6.24 with option --enable-sockets, resolved the problem.
i do’t know why.

Answer (score 0):

To get sockets to be working you need to run the following commandline commands for ubuntu linux:

1. `phpenmod sockets`
2. `apache2ctl restart` - to restart the apache2 server